# To Assign a random number for the agents inside a node

Tags: anylogic

I am building this Ped model , using the pedestrian library .
how can i assign a random number for number of agents inside a node and to call them out to do something based on that number  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's imagine the following scenario, you have a node, with capacity restriction where you get access to the "on enter" action. There, any time a pedestrian enters the node, it will be added to the pedsInNode ArrayList.

[image]

then the button does something with those agents, for example freeing them from the pedWait block as follows:

```
int x=uniform_discr(1,4);//random number between 1 and 4
int count=0;
ArrayList <Pedestrian> peds=new ArrayList();
for(Pedestrian p : pedsInNode){
        peds.add(p);    
        count++;
        if(count==x)
            break;
}
for(Pedestrian p : peds){
    pedWait.free(p);
    pedsInNode.remove(p);
}
```

Comment: Well Said Felipe  !!